# TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable with pd.read_sql

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc, plotly-dash

Not sure why i get the following error: **TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable** when i run the below.. any ideas?

```
import pyodbc 
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                          'Server=LDN01939344;'
                          'Database=EData;'
                          'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
                         )

sql = 'SELECT top 100 * from EData.dbo.DTData'
data = pd.read_sql(sql,conn)

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in data.columns],
    data=data.to_dict('records'),

     style_header={
        'backgroundColor': 'rgb(230, 230, 230)',
        'fontWeight': 'bold'
    }

)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False,ssl_context='adhoc')
```

then i get that error- any idea what i can do???

```
  File "C:\Users\zoeS\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\zoeS-a\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\_plotly_utils\utils.py", line 44, in encode
    encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
  File "C:\Users\zoeS\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\zoeS\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\zoeS-a\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\_plotly_utils\utils.py", line 113, in default
    return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
  File "C:\Users\zoeS\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried the following:

```
objectcolumns=data.loc[:, data.dtypes == object].columns.to_list()
```

Then

```
for i in objectcolumns:
    print(i)
    data[i]=data[i].str.decode("utf-8")
```

however when i do this i get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 5: invalid start byte
```

Comment: can you post full stack trace, I mean in which line you got the error?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah added it - or some of it stackexchange won't let me post all of it

Comment: your log is not helping me to find the issue. Can you suspect which line of code causes the issue?

Comment: I think it might be to do with the SQL connection, i mean it all runs but not sure if this is due to some unicode eror

Comment: It looks like your table has one or more columns that contain binary data (e.g., a `varbinary` column). Try omitting them from the `read_sql` query.

Comment: yeah as @GordThompson suggested, remove bytes and give a shot.

Comment: by this do you mean somehing like:

Comment: data[i]=data[i].str.decode("utf-8") where i is columns in my table? pls view edit

Comment: @Maths12 - No, I meant `SELECT TOP 100 col1, col2, col4 FROM ...` instead of `SELECT TOP 100 * FROM ...`

Comment: i still get that same error :/

Comment: @Maths12 - Don't try and decode anything, simply omit any binary columns from your query. Also remember to use `@...` in replies so the person to whom you are replying gets notified.

Comment: @GordThompson sorry i will use @. So i think i am getting closer.. i have about 90 columns so i have painfully went through trial and error to see what column is preventing it from loading. it seems i have a column where it contains values like: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\xcc@\xa4' this . Its the timestamp column should i parse it

Comment: @Maths12 - No, just omit it. As noted in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it is really not particularly useful to end-users anyway.